# How to make a Profile Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

I need a way how can I slide a whole site with a full-screen profile to the next profile with touch events in Javascript, hope you can help me thank you.

The Design is ready and I just need a function for and how to make the function works.

Comment: What have you done? No codes? Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask in stackoverflow

Comment: you can't asking source code here

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) which is an example of Carousel. You have to use bootstrap framework though. Just import it in the `head` of your html. You don't need to implement any javascript with this.